# Unknown message digest in crypto and Node 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Here is part of my code that uses [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) and works fine with Node v8.15.0:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
...
const sign = crypto.createSign('DSA');
```

---

When I switched to **Node 10**:

```
nvm install 10
node --version
v10.15.1
```

The same source code **returns error**:

```
     Error: Unknown message digest
      at new Sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:26:16)
      at Object.createSign (crypto.js:137:10)
```

How to get **DSA** in Node 10 and crypto?

---

Additional information:
Node 10 `crypto.getHashes()` returns (no DSA!):

```
[ 'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  'RSA-MDC2',
  'RSA-RIPEMD160',
  'RSA-SHA1',
  'RSA-SHA1-2',
  'RSA-SHA224',
  'RSA-SHA256',
  'RSA-SHA384',
  'RSA-SHA512',
  'blake2b512',
  'blake2s256',
  'md4',
  'md4WithRSAEncryption',
  'md5',
  'md5-sha1',
  'md5WithRSAEncryption',
  'mdc2',
  'mdc2WithRSA',
  'ripemd',
  'ripemd160',
  'ripemd160WithRSA',
  'rmd160',
  'sha1',
  'sha1WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha224',
  'sha224WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha256',
  'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha384',
  'sha384WithRSAEncryption',
  'sha512',
  'sha512WithRSAEncryption',
  'ssl3-md5',
  'ssl3-sha1',
  'whirlpool' ]
```

While in Node 8 I get (truncated as SO doesn't like too much code):

```
[ 'DSA',
  'DSA-SHA',
  'DSA-SHA1',
  'DSA-SHA1-old',
  'RSA-MD4',
  'RSA-MD5',
  ...
  'whirlpool' ]
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20302) for this in the GitHub repository for Node.js. It basically comes does to the fact that support for DSA has been removed in the underlying OpenSSL, which is being used by Node.js.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20302#issuecomment-461037595):

> `DSA-SHA1` has been renamed to `DSS1`

But:

> However, if I run in node v10.15.1 `crypto.getHashes()` then I don't get `DSS1` too.

So, from my point of view your only option is to switch to another signature algorithm, or to try to find a third party module that implements what you need independent of Node.js's `crypto` module (and hence, independent of OpenSSL).

Comment: You basically found my own comment on GitHub while I was researching the issue after I posted my own question in SO :) Anyway, using a different module may do the trick. I'll research this path...

Comment: Haha, sorry I didn‘t realize that! 

Comment: @iaforek did you find a solution in the end?